# Using jQuery Templates in Struts2

Tags: jquery, jsp, struts2, jquery-templates, ognl

I am attempting to update a page using Struts2 ([using jOWL to display an ontology](http://jowl.ontologyonline.org/)). The original HTML page uses jQuery templates, having several lines such as:

```
<h2 class="propertybox title" data-jowl="rdfs:label">${rdfs:label}</h2>
<span class="alt">${?p}</span><span>: </span><span>${?t}</span>
```

to display a variable determined in a jQuery script file.  This works well enough as a .html file. However, the .jsp file thinks I am attempting to use Struts variables rather than a jQuery template.  It crashes when it encounters the colon and question mark.

I did find some [jQuery Struts2 libraries](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/FAQ), but I didn't see any tags that would map to jQuery templates. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery tmpl and JSP code not playing nicely.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380074/jquery-tmpl-and-jsp-code-not-playing-nicely)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that a jsp thinks ${} is EL.  So you need to somehow escape part of the express, this isn't going to be pretty:

```
From the JSP 2 spec:

For literal values that include the character sequence ${, JSP 2.0 provides a
way to escape them by using the sequence ${'${'. For example, the following
character sequence is translated into the literal value ${expr}:

${'${'}expr}
```

Source: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t129212-ot-jsp-escape-el-expressions.html

Comment: That does get it to compile (as does [escaping the question mark](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/issues/359))!

However, in both cases, it displays text rather than a template variable result (as in: ${rdfs:label} rather than Wine). I'm not sure if it's just having issues with the Tomcat server (or Eclipse web browser) or if there's something else I'm missing.

Comment: I'm starting to feel like there is something I'm missing. jQuery templates are client side. So as long as the page arrives escaped tomcat or any application server is no longer responsible. The client then loads the page and executes a jQuery script which then parses those variables.

Comment: As it turns out, there was an Internet Explorer issue with the script (which, for some reason, only shows up in the Struts project and not the .html version of the same thing). The template data showed up fine if I changed the extension of the file I was trying to view or looked at it in Firefox. I'm still figuring that one out.

Thanks! Your input was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In regards to EL and the suggested pattern:

```
${'${'}expr}
```

According to Oracle you can disable the EL parsing: [Deactivating EL Expression Evaluation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial-update2/doc/JSPIntro13.html#wp83214)

```
<%@ page isELIgnored ="true|false" %>
```

> Because the pattern that identifies EL expressions--${ }--was not reserved in the JSP specifications before JSP 2.0, there may be applications where such a pattern is intended to pass through verbatim. To prevent the pattern from being evaluated, you can deactivate EL evaluation.
>
> The valid values of this attribute are true and false. If it is true, EL expressions are ignored when they appear in static text or tag attributes. If it is false, EL expressions are evaluated by the container.