# how to declare jsp not to parse jQuery template variable

Tags: jquery, jsp, templates

I have my JSP with jQuery templates

```
<script id="movieTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"> 
  {{tmpl "titleTemplate"}}
  <tr class="detail"><td>Director: ${Director}</td></tr>
</script>
```

when my JSP got compiled and creating the html the html looks like below

```
<script id="movieTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"> 
  {{tmpl "titleTemplate"}}
  <tr class="detail"><td>Director: </td></tr>
</script>
```

Is there any convention or any other alternate approach to convey JSP to differentiate with server variable vs java script variable `${Director}`?

Comment: I found the reference at [jquery template][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792023/using-jquery-templates-in-struts2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in stackoverflow; the reference for the same [Jquery template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792023/using-jquery-templates-in-struts2)

As per the JSP 2.0 spec

For literal values that include the character sequence ${, JSP 2.0 provides a
way to escape them by using the sequence ${'${'. For example, the following
character sequence is translated into the literal value ${expr}:

${'${'}expr}

Answer (score 0):

You can write jQuery instead of $ in your jquery variables.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){});
```

instead of

```
$(document).ready(function(){});
```